# What is the default value of flex in Expandable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Suppose i have 5 containers, all wrapped in expanded widgets, what happens if i provide value of flex for only few of them. Is is set to zero or does it disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. They are set to 1 by default.